# ¿Como puedo mostrar la sumatoria total en input de tipo number en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una tabla cuando agrego los totales, muestra la sumatoria total en el input pero la sumatoria no corresponde, si alguien de la comunidad me puede apoyar con la solución de este problema

Imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Formulario

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <select name="producto" id="producto" required>
      <option value="-1">Seleccione Producto</option>
      <c:forEach items="${productos}" var="producto">
        <option value="${producto.idproducto}">${producto.nomproducto}</option>
      </c:forEach>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" autofocus />
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="pesobruto" id="pesobruto" onkeyup="restar();" autofocus />
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="tara" id="tara" onkeyup="restar();" autofocus />
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="pesoneto" id="pesoneto" disabled autofocus />
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="preciocompra" id="preciocompra" autofocus />
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="descuento" value="0" disabled />
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <button type="submit" onclick="agregarFila();" class="btn btn-success">agregar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tabla2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Precio Compra</th>
        <th>Peso Neto</th>
        <th>Descuento</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="form-group row justify-content-end">
  <label for="precio_bruto" class="control-label col-md-2">Precio Bruto</label>
  <label for="descuento" class="control-label col-md-2">Descuento</label>
  <label for="descuento" class="control-label col-md-2">Precio Neto</label>
  <label for="descuento" class="control-label col-md-2">I.G.V</label>
  <label for="descuento" class="control-label col-md-2">Total</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group row justify-content-end">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pbruto" autofocus />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descuento1" autofocus />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pneto" autofocus />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="igv" autofocus />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mtotal" autofocus />
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```javascript
function agregarFila(){
    
    
     let cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
     let preciocompra = document.getElementById('preciocompra').value;
     let pesoneto = document.getElementById('pesoneto').value;
     let descuento = document.getElementById('descuento').value;
     let producto = document.getElementById('producto').options[document.getElementById('producto').selectedIndex].text;    
     let total=Number.parseFloat((preciocompra*pesoneto)-descuento).toFixed(2);
    
    
     let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
      
    
      let newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
      
    
      let cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
      let cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
      let cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
      let cel4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
      let cel5 = newRow.insertCell(4);
      let cel6 = newRow.insertCell(5);     
      
      cel1.innerHTML = producto;
      cel2.innerHTML = cantidad;
      cel3.innerHTML = preciocompra;
      cel4.innerHTML = pesoneto;
      cel5.innerHTML = descuento;
      cel6.innerHTML = total;            

     
      
      for (let i = 0; i < cel6.length; i++) {
          if(Number(cel6[i].value))
              
              total += (parseFloat(cel6[i].value) || 0 );
             
          
          }   
      
      
     document.getElementById('mtotal').value = total;
   
    
}
```

Comment: puedes asignar por defecto un valor 0 (cero) en la caja de texto. Tomas el valor que contenga la caja de texto y le aumentas el valor cuando le das el boton agregar y el valor de la caja de texto lo recalculas cada que vayas agregando un valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya le di solución dejo el código

```
function agregarFila(){


 let cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
 let preciocompra = document.getElementById('preciocompra').value;
 let pesoneto = document.getElementById('pesoneto').value;
 let descuento = document.getElementById('descuento').value;
 let producto = document.getElementById('producto').options[document.getElementById('producto').selectedIndex].text;    

 
 let subtotal=Number.parseFloat((preciocompra*pesoneto)-descuento).toFixed(2);
    
 
let impuesto=Number.parseFloat(subtotal*0.19).toFixed(2);
    impuesto= document.getElementById('impuesto').value;
let total=Number.parseFloat(subtotal).toFixed(2)+Number.parseFloat(impuesto).toFixed(2);
    total= document.getElementById('total').value;
```

//  let table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

```
    let table = document.getElementById('tabla2');
  let newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
  

  let cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  let cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  let cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  let cel4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
  let cel5 = newRow.insertCell(4);
  let cel6 = newRow.insertCell(5);     
  
  cel1.innerHTML = producto;
  cel2.innerHTML = cantidad;
  cel3.innerHTML = preciocompra;
  cel4.innerHTML = pesoneto;
  cel5.innerHTML = descuento;
  cel6.innerHTML = subtotal;      
  

  
  calcularSubtotal();
```

}
function calcularSubtotal(){

```
 var table = document.getElementById('tabla2');
    let subtotal = 0
    for(let i = 1; i<table.rows.length; i++){
        subtotal+=Number(table.rows[i].cells[5].innerText)
    }
    const totalInput = document.getElementById('subtotal')
    totalInput.value=subtotal
```

}